# How to add a custom field in Flask-Marshmallow which is not a part of my SQLAlchemy Model

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

Suppose I have my Model class as below.

```
class BankAccount(db.Model):
    a = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    b = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

And my Schema looks like the below.

```
class CreateAccountSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = BankAccount
        load_instance = True
        ordered = True
```

But here I want to define a field **c** which doesnt exists in my Model class as it should only be used for dump(ing) values and not storing in the database.
Something like...

```
class CreateAccountSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = BankAccount
        dump_only = ('c',)
        load_instance = True
        ordered = True
        c = #somedefination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class CreateAccountSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = BankAccount
        load_instance = True
        ordered = True
        c = fields.Method("get_data")

    def get_data(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, "data"):
            return obj.data
        return None
```

That would dump the additional field.
You could use it like this:

```
bank_account = db.session.query(BankAccount).first()
bank_account.data = "whatever"
schema = CreateAccountSchema()
schema.dump(bank_account)
```

More infos [here](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_fields.html#method-and-function-field-deserialization).